# Integrating Busted tests into a Maven build cycle

Tags: maven, integration, lua-busted

My recent task at work is to look into integrating some tests we built for our custom Kong API Gateway plugins into our standard Maven build.

The build currently just moves configuration scripts to the right place, packages the plugins in such a way that our version of the gateway can be easily deployed with a shell script.

The tests are written in Busted, and a bit of research showed that around two years ago it wasn't possible to run Busted tests with the standard Maven plugins. Is this still not possible in 2016?

Many thanks.

Comment: Writing your own maven plugin is remarkably easy, and with that you can do almost anything you want, such as run tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution:

Busted's output handler is configurable to allow output in multiple formats. One of these formats is TAP (Test Anything Protocol) which is easily parsed by various Maven plugins.